# How to prevent a fragment in a fragment pager from being recreated on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, pager

I am aware that normally for fragments you can do something like this in your activitiy's onCreate to retrieve an already created fragment that has .setRetainInstance(true) on orientation change instead of creating a new fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        TestFragment test = new TestFragment();
        test.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, test, "your_fragment_tag").commit();
    } else {
        TestFragment test = (TestFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("your_fragment_tag");
    }
}
```

My question is how can I retain and retrieve such a fragment that is within a viewpager? Recreating the fragment is not something I want. Even if I could retrieve these fragments tag the viewpager handles attaching the fragment so it does not seem it would be possible to check for the existing fragment and retrieving that rather than creating a new one. Here is my activity and pager:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));


    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:                       
                    return new FragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new SettingsFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` automatically tag the fragment, so finding the fragment by tag is not an option here. However you can keep a reference to your fragment that is created by the view pager by overriding `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` method of the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class.

```
   Fragment myFragment = null;

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:                       
                    return new FragmentA();
                case 1:
                    return new SettingsFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            myFragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if (myFragment != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fragment retrieved " + myFragment.toString());
            }

            return myFragment;
        }
    }
```